# PHP - imap_delete deletes the email just after visiting the webmail

Tags: php, email, imap

I am getting my inbox emails using

`$hostname = '{imap.one.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';`

Everything works fine however, when I try to delete an email from my script, it deletes the email chosen just after I login into the server webmail in this case one.com webmail.

I am using

```
$msgid = '1'; //For example

imap_delete($mbox, "$msgid:$msgid");
```

Any idea how to get my script to delete the email without visiting the webmail server?

Comment: You have to commit your transaction with the imap server. Otherwise the messages will stay marked for deletion, not more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](http://php.net/imap_delete):

> Messages marked for deletion will stay in the mailbox until either imap_expunge() is called or imap_close() is called with the optional parameter CL_EXPUNGE.

You should either:

- Call `imap_expunge()` after your imap_delete call
- Add `imap_close($connection, CL_EXPUNGE);` at the end of your script